# ethernet interfaces are sometimes renamed to 'renameX' on startup

Tags: ubuntu, ethernet, network-adapter, rename

I've installed a recent daily build of Ubuntu Trusty on several HP dl380e 2U servers. These servers have 4 x 1Gb onboard NICs. In addition, I've installed a PCIe 2 port 10Gb NIC in each server.

The linux kernel is naming the 10Gb ports 'p4p1' and 'p4p2' respectively, and the onboard ports 'em1' to 'em4'.

I haven't seen this naming convention before, but I can live with it, but now to the problem:

On bootup, the 10GB ports are occasionally being renamed to 'renameX' where 'X' is typically a number between 2-5.

This is obviously a problem since it breaks everything that's trying to use the interface; the OS and software simply think the interface has disappeared.

Does anyone know why this is happening/how I can resolve it?

edit:
This question is similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/210423/why-have-my-network-interfaces-been-renamed-after-installing-ubuntu-and-how-do) one, but different in that the interfaces seem to consistently have the same MAC addresses.

Comment: the naming seam to have change with newer kernel : http://askubuntu.com/questions/267172/new-nic-device-naming-in-12-10

Comment: @chaput thanks for the link, it's good to understand the reasoning behind the naming convention.

Comment: you may want to try this : http://serverfault.com/questions/483220/network-interface-naming-conflict-ubuntu